# Search filter with multiple Comboboxes?

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a a search filter with multiple `Comboboxes`,
the code works but just in the first test, the problem is when i want to make another search after nothing is shown on my `datagirdview`.
Here is the code, i don't know whats the problem?

```
string aFilter = string.Empty;
string bFilter = string.Empty;
string cFilter = string.Empty;
```

---

```
private void applyFilter()
{
    generateFilter(bFilter);
    generateFilter(cFilter);
}

private void generateFilter(string filter)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aFilter))
        {
            aFilter = filter;
        }
        else
        {
            aFilter += " AND " + filter;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(table);
    bFilter = string.Format("[Nom complet] LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    applyFilter();
    dv.RowFilter = aFilter;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv1 = new DataView(table);
    cFilter = string.Format("[Type programme] LIKE '%{0}%'", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    applyFilter();
    dv1.RowFilter = aFilter;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv1;
}
```

Comment: what is your applyFilter function

Comment: `just in the first test` ? can explain?

Comment: @lomed it filters the dataview just in the first time, but when i change the value of any combobox to make another filter, it does not work and no result is shown.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Its a method to add filter rules

Comment: first time = first combobox choice, or initial form state? also, put a breakpoint in the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method, in the `dv1.RowFilter = aFilter` line and observe the value of `aFilter`.

Comment: Not first combobox, But when i choose an item from the combobox1 the dataview is filtered, then i choose an item from the combobox2 and the dataview is filtered again but from the last result. tell now everything is okay
But now when i want to change the item from any combobox to make another filtrered result = Nothing is shown on my dataview.

Comment: it means after the first success-ed filter result, No matter what combobox i change it item, the result is always Null = Dataview = empty

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the `aFilter`. each filter added to it again and again.

try:

```
string bFilter = "";
string cFilter = "";

private string CombinFilters()
{
    var a = new[] { bFilter, cFilter }; //all filters to combin
    var notNull = a.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

    if (notNull.Any())
        return string.Join(" AND ", notNull);
    else
        return null;
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(table);
    bFilter = string.Format("[Nom complet] LIKE '%{0}%'", "123");
    dv.RowFilter = CombinFilters();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(table);
    cFilter = string.Format("[Type programme] LIKE '%{0}%'", "345");
    dv.RowFilter = CombinFilters();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```